# config.assets.debug = true suddenly stops working in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have this bizarre behavior that I cannot even debug. Usually development is supposed to run a little slower than production. Not only is it now running extremely fast, but it does not recognize my javascript code (it does recognize javascript outside of the assets/javascripts directory), unless I modify the javascript code and refresh page or simply just refresh the page (and then it will only work for that one request).

The reason why I am stumped is because I have the following in /config/environments/development.rb:

```
config.assets.debug = true
```

Furthermore, my development.rb is set to the factory defaults. 
Any idea how I can further troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Are you using turbolinks?

Comment: @michaelsnowden yes I am using turbolinks

Comment: Try disabling it. Then restart your server, and revisit the pages where your javascript doesn't work.

Comment: When you say disable, you mean to comment it out in application.js?

Comment: Just remove it from application.js temporarily.

Comment: @michaelsnowden no that didn't fix the problem. I always had turbolinks there and it was never a problem.